# constructing Fourier sine and cosine series (confused on how to determine the period, L)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If I have a function f(x) like this:

\begin{cases} 
      0 & 0 \leq x\leq1 
\\ 
      1 & 1< x \leq 2
   \end{cases}

I want to find sine series, for example so I use the formula below:
[image]

My issue is, how to determine L? I assumed at the beginning that we look at the intervals, and see the amount in which they differ, like 1-0 = 1, or 2-1 = 1. But this is clearely wrong because in this prolem L =2. How do you determine L, in general?

Also, function graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for $L$ such that $f(x+L)=f(x)$. The intervals of constancy are not important, it is the repeat.

Comment: Okay, thank you! but what is the technique to determine that? for example, am I expected to imagine the graph?

Comment: You are only given the function over a range of $2$ so you are using it all, or you are forcing it to repeat. Either way you know $L$ here. Other times it is not so clear. A graph can help

Comment: I'm using it all? I'm sorry, but I'm very confused by the explanation, but I attached the graph

Comment: As given your function is only given for x from 0 to 2. The graph you have drawn extends beyond that and has no period at all

Comment: this is part of the solution to reflect about the origin and extend the graph..

Comment: anyway, I think I know what you mean now, thanks!